# Automatic list generation; Python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I apologise in advance for having such an vague title, but it's hard for me to conceptualise the problem precisely.

I have a script that checks if a certain `name` is in a text. If the name is in the text, the script appends a `1` to a list specifically dedicated to that `name`, and if it's not in the text it appends a `0`.

It looks like this:

```
import re
import csv
from itertools import izip

names = ['peter', 'john', 'thomas', 'george']
texts = ['peter is awesome', 'john is lazy', 'thomas is thomas','george is curious']

peter_matched = []
john_matched = []
thomas_matched = []
george_matched = []

for text in texts:
    for name in names:
        if name == 'peter':
            if re.match(name, text):
                peter_matched.append(1)
            else:
                peter_matched.append(0)
        if name == 'john':
            if re.match(name, text):
                john_matched.append(1)
            else:
                john_matched.append(0)
        if name == 'thomas':
            if re.match(name, text):
                thomas_matched.append(1)
            else:
                thomas_matched.append(0)
        if name == 'george':
            if re.match(name, text):
                george_matched.append(1)
            else:
                george_matched.append(0)

with open('output_names.csv', 'wb') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f)
        w.writerows(izip(texts, peter_matched, john_matched, thomas_matched, george_matched))
```

Now as you can see, it's an ugly mishmash of `if/else` statements. What's even more problematic, is that I have to create a separate dedicated list for every `name` to hold the matched information and then write it into a `.csv`. In my real script I would need to cross-reference thousands of texts and hundreds of names, so writing a dedicated `name_matched` list for every item is not exactly a fun task.

So my question is: is it possible to tell Python to generate these lists automatically by taking an item's name from the `names` list and appending it to some pre-existing string, like `_matched`.

In other words, I would like the lists `peter_matched`, `john_matched`, etc. to be created automatically.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First thought: if your regex searches are along the lines of `'peter'`, there's no need for a regex. Just use the `in` operator. Second thought: are you looking for a counter?

Comment: I would prefer dictionary like this `{"peter": [1,0,0,1]}`

Comment: I use regex as an example, since I would need to use regex in my real script. It true that it's definitely redundant here.

Comment: If the creation of CSV is important for you, my answer below addresses also this facet of the problem.

Comment: @gboffi yes! thank you. the .csv is definitely very important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create `dict` of lists and retrieve each list based on `name` string.

```
names = ['peter', 'john', 'thomas', 'george']
texts = ['peter is awesome', 'john is lazy', 'thomas is thomas','george is curious']

matched = {n: [] for n in names}

for text in texts:
    for name in names:
        if re.match(name, text):
            matched[name].append(1)
        else:
            matched[name].append(0)

print matched
# {'john': [0, 1, 0, 0], 'thomas': [0, 0, 1, 0], 'peter': [1, 0, 0, 0], 'george': [0, 0, 0, 1]}
```

Comment: Why `if re.match(name, text):` rather than `if name in text:` or `if text.startswith(name)`? Much faster and clearer than a regex.

Answer (score 2):

### One-liner using dict comprehension (since python 2.7):

```
{name: [1 if name in text else 0 for text in texts ] for name in names}
```

### Building dict name by name

Building dictionary key by key (classical way):

```
def check_names(names, texts):
    res = {}
    for name in names:
        res[name] = [1 if name in text else 0 for text in texts]
    return res
```

### Bonus: pytest tests

If you want to test it by pytest, put following code into `test_names.py`:

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def names():
    return ['peter', 'john', 'thomas', 'george']


@pytest.fixture
def texts():
    return [
        'peter is awesome',
        'john is lazy',
        'thomas is thomas',
        'george is curious']


def check_names(names, texts):
    res = {}
    for name in names:
        res[name] = [1 if name in text else 0 for text in texts]
    return res


def check_names2(names, texts):
    res = {name: [1 if name in text else 0
                  for text in texts
                  ]
           for name in names
           }
    return res


def test_it(names, texts):
    expected_result = {"peter":  [1, 0, 0, 0],
                       "john":   [0, 1, 0, 0],
                       "thomas": [0, 0, 1, 0],
                       "george": [0, 0, 0, 1],
                       }
    result = check_names2(names, texts)
    assert result == expected_result
```

and run

```
$ py.test -sv test_names.py
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary for that. You can do something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
counts = defaultdict(int)
for text in tests:
    for name in names:
        if name in text:
            counts[name] += 1
```

Or if you're looking for exact 0s and 1s, you can initialize the dictionary with string type:

```
counts = defaultdict(str)
for text in tests:
    for name in names:
        counts[name] += '1' if name in text else '0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a separate list for each name, use a `dict` type, and specifically the [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
dict_of_list_names = defaultdict(list)

for text in texts:
    for name in names:
        to_append = 1 if name in text else 0
        dict_of_list_names[name].append(to_append)
```

Also, from the example you don't need to use regex. Use a `for in` instead, as it is faster.

Answer (score 1):

The 1st part is easy, convert the list of names to a dictionary of empty lists

```
names = {name:[] for name in names}
```

to fill in the lists, is easy as well

```
for t in texts:
    for n in names:
        names[n].append(1 if n in t else 0)
```

(note that for the example you gave regexps are overkill).

The hard part, imho, is writing your results to file in a most similar way to the one you showed... I inserted a header line because `names.values()` does not return the lists in a given order, but you are assured that the order of `.values()` is the same order of `.keys()` so, writing a header line with the keys of `names` seems to me the easier way to have an useful CSV.

```
with open('output_names.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(['text']+list(names.keys()))
    w.writerows(zip(texts, *names.values()))
```

The result is

```
$ cat output_names.csv
text,john,george,peter,thomas
peter is awesome,0,0,1,0
john is lazy,1,0,0,0
thomas is thomas,0,0,0,1
george is curious,0,1,0,0
$
```